# Route requests to webservice through BizTalk orchestration.

Tags: web-services, soap, architecture, biztalk, soa

I am going to consume a webservice. The requirements forces me to go through an orchestration that handles some logging etc before the request is made.

The best solution I can think of is to consume the web service and publish the orchestration as another webservice that can be called instead.

Is there a way to for example intercept the request to the web service and force an orchestration to start? What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you even need biztalk for that? If you can't edit the source code of that webservice, then you can build your own service (WCF), that will do some custom logic before routing it to the main webservice. If you think, that you SHOULD use Biztalk here, then your solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use BizTalk, what you describe is how it would be done.  Except, you can implement the main process as Messaging only.  Here are some articles:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richardbpi/archive/2006/11/10/using-only-biztalk-messaging-with-request-response-on-both-ends.aspx

http://ershadnozari.blogspot.com/2010/10/request-response-to-solicit-response.html

Once that is working, you can then have an Orchestration subscribing to the initial Request message on the side where it can do it's work.